# Where to find Google Analytics event object details in report after DataLayer push

Tags: google-analytics-4

I am using Google Tag Manager and DataLayer to track events on a website, for example the **view_item_list** event. Along with the event, I am pushing an "ecommerce" object, so my push looks like this:

```
dataLayer.push({
    event: 'view_item_list',
    ecommerce: {
        items: productObj
    }
});
```

projectObj looks something like this (product names changed to xxx, yyy, zzz):

```
[
   {
      "item_name":"xxx",
      "item_category":"",
      "item_id":"",
      "item_variation_id":"",
      "sku":"",
      "description":"",
      "quantity":"",
      "price":""
   },
   {
      "item_name":"yyy",
      "item_category":"",
      "item_id":"",
      "item_variation_id":"",
      "sku":"",
      "description":"",
      "quantity":"",
      "price":""
   },
   {
      "item_name":"zzz",
      "item_category":"",
      "item_id":"",
      "item_variation_id":"",
      "sku":"",
      "description":"",
      "quantity":"",
      "price":""
   }
]
```

In my Realtime and Engagement reports, I can see the events being tracked. In the Monetization/Ecommerce Purchases report, I can see item views and add-to-carts. However, I don't see where I can view something like the details of a view_item_list event. Is there a way to drill down to show counts of specific products in view_item_list events? Or must I structure my DataLayer pushes in a different way?

Comment: We might need to see how you configured the Tag to send event to GA4.

Comment: The dataLayer.push command in my description is where that happens, and that is working. I am just not sure how to find any of the "ecommerce" data in the reports.

Comment: Yes I know your datalayer code looks good in here. But in GTM you still need to configure the `GA4 Event Tag` in a right way then it will pick up the ecommerce object within the event.  So that's why I might need to check how you configure the tag in GTM.

Comment: I guess the answer to that is, I don't know. I didn't setup GTM and not sure I have access to it. The e-commerce object as described was setup by a previous developer in other parts of the site, I am just re-using what I found. I assume all of this should be viewable tagmanager.google.com, and I should see the tag there with configuration options?